# How to return the directory of a given executable?

Tags: shell, which

If I want to return the path of a given executable, I can run:

```
which mysql
```

Which returns for example:

```
/usr/bin/mysql
```

I'd like to return only:

```
/usr/bin
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
executable=mysql

executable_path=$(command -v -- "$executable") &&
  dirname -- "$executable_path"
```

([don't use `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22565)).

Of course, that won't work if `$executable` is a shell builtin, function or alias. I'm not aware of any shell where `mysql` is a builtin. It won't be a function or alias unless you defined them earlier, but then you should know about it. An exception to that could be `bash` which supports exported functions.

```
$ bash -c 'command -v mysql'
/usr/bin/mysql
$ mysql='() { echo test;}' bash -c 'command -v mysql'
mysql
```

Comment: +1, but this would be even better IMO with a short explanation of *why* one shouldn't use `which`.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I attempted to explain why `which` is bad in my answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @slm Nice! +1 to you too.

Comment: Would that it were so simple! Sometimes this prints `.`. (Because there's an alias, which `which` isn't aware of.) Zsh has the very convenient `=mysql` syntax, but unfortunately it doesn't stack with `${…##*/}` or `…:h`.

Comment: @Gilles, you can do `${${:-mysql}:c:h}` though. ksh and zsh have `whence -p` to return paths of commands even if there's a builtin/alias/function for it, but then that might not be what you want as it's not what the shell would invoke.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ah, I hadn't thought of `:c`, nice. But actually I made a mistake, `=mysql` does stack with glob qualifiers. An alias or function could of course do anything, but having an alias that calls the command with the same name with additional parameters is very common.

Answer (score 4):

#### which

In general this command should be avoided.

Why?

Because it uses your current environment when constructing the `$PATH` that it's going to evaluate when looking for executables. This can lead to confusion when dealing with shell scripts and such, that will potentially be using the `$PATH` as constructed by your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` files when executed.

For example:

```
# path to start
$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/sam/bin

# let's change it
$ export PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# simulate a new env. for a shell script
$ bash -lc "echo \$PATH"
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/sam/bin
```

Notice that the shell script if executed would have the original environment, not the current one!

#### type

You can also use the command `type` to locate executables within your environment:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

Or to see everything, use the `-a` switch:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
```

`type` will show you aliases as well as the location. For finding the directory though, @StephaneChazelas solution of using `command` is best.

#### whereis

You can also use the command `whereis` but this doesn't use your environment, it has a hardcoded set of directories that it looks in. See [man whereis](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis) for more details.

#### locate

This one might confuse people but some distros include a tool that runs from a cron job, typically daily, that scans the entire disk and builds a little database file which you can then search using the `locate` command.

- The cron job is called `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate.cron` on my Fedora 14 system.
- The tool doing the scanning is called `/usr/bin/updatedb`.
- The DB file is located here: `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`.

Using what I'd consider a bit of a hack you can coax `locate` to only look for files that are named `ls` as follows:

```
$ locate -b '\ls'
/bin/ls
/usr/share/javadoc/java-1.6.0-openjdk/api/org/w3c/dom/ls
/usr/share/javadoc/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre/api/plugin/dom/org/w3c/dom/ls
/usr/share/locale/l10n/ls
/var/cache/abrt-di/usr/src/debug/gcc-4.5.1-20100924/libjava/classpath/external/w3c_dom/org/w3c/dom/ls
/var/cache/abrt-di/usr/src/debug/gcc-4.5.1-20100924/libjava/classpath/gnu/xml/dom/ls
```

The above works because you're `\` is a globbing character, so this disables the implicit replacement of `ls` with `*ls*`.

See the [locate man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) for more details.

#### whatis

A lesser known tool is called `whatis`. This one is similar to `locate`, so it's backed by a DB. It is useful for finding out commands however:

```
$ whatis ls
ls                   (1)  - list directory contents
ls                   (1p)  - list directory contents
```

The tool is invoked from a cron job, `/etc/cron.daily/makewhatis.cron`. However, `makewhatis` builds its database from the `man` pages on your system.

You can see more about it in the [makewhatis man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/8/makewhatis).

#### Just the directory name?

You can use the command `dirpath` against any of the output produced by the commands I mentioned above to get just the directory component.

`dirpath` does no checking so you can give it just about any type of path to a file and it will give you the directory piece:

```
$ dirname /some/path/to/a/script
/some/path/to/a
```

Comment: I don't understand your first section about "why not using which". I've created a [separate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22565) for it as [we need to have a canonical one here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689). Feel free to add your answer there.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - will do. Didn't see this before. Are you suggesting the entire answer or just that section? Also do I copy/paste or move it somehow?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - just saw your Q&A. Show off 8-).

Answer (score 1):

Its rather simple with xargs:

```
which mysql | xargs dirname
```

Answer (score 0):

As [others](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85198/how-to-return-the-directory-of-a-given-executable/85199#85199) have [explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85198/how-to-return-the-directory-of-a-given-executable/85201#85201), [don't use `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249).

You can write a little shell function that iterates over the `PATH` variable.

```
which-directory () (
  IFS=:
  set -g
  for d in $PATH; do
    if [ -z "$d" ]; then d=.; fi
    if [ -x "$d/$1" ]; then printf '%s\n' "$d"; return; fi
  done
  return 1
)
```

Alternatively, you can call `command -v`. This reports aliases and functions as well as external commands. In case you have an alias or function `mysql` that calls the external command of the same name with additional parameters, you can call `command -v` in a newly-started shell that doesn't have any functions or aliases defined. Note that this does the right thing only if the alias or function calls the external command of the same name. The following two one-liners are equivalent (assuming you have no directory or executable file name on your PATH containing a newline).

```
dirname -- "$(sh -c 'command -v "$0"' -- mysql)"
sh -c 'command -v "$0"' -- mysql | sed -e 's!.*/!!'
```

In zsh, this one-liner does the same thing:

```
echo =mysql(:h)
```

Answer (score 0):

dirname is simplest way of achieving this:

```
$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
$ dirname `which mysql`
/usr/bin
```